# about blocking system call in the multi-threading

Tags: java

While studying a java-based web framework Spring, I had the following question.

When a system call is called on a Java multi-threading process,
other threads cannot execute the corresponding system call?

ex) like read operation to socket
`static native int read0(FileDescriptor fd, long address, int len) throws IOException;`

I created a thread and called a native method that invokes a blocking system call
but it was difficult to judge the result about this

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why does it intrest you what Java threads do at the system call level? You can't control or access it anyway.

Comment: In a web application with many concurrent requests, if each thread cannot execute the same system call concurrently,
I was wondering if it dosen't affect the speed of response.

Comment: You are going way too deep level with this. You can't tell what the threads will do. Even if they block, it's not under your control and not something you'll be able to change. Nevertheless, Java-based web applications work very efficiently all over the world. Only optimize when you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a system call is called on a Java multi-threading process, other threads cannot execute the corresponding system call?

Java itself has no mechanism for (directly) making system calls, so this is a question of native methods and particular JVM implementations, which both boil down to the underlying hardware and OS.  I am not aware of any modern, general-purpose SMP operating system where execution of a system call by one userspace thread blocks execution of any system call by another userspace thread at the syscall interface.

However, the kernel might internally serialize the service of some requests.  To take your example, if requests to read from the same socket are in flight simultaneously in the kernel of a POSIX system, then the kernel will service one read in full, then the other.  It will not provide the same data to both reads, nor split the data among reads any other way than I just described.

Comment: "~one userspace thread blocks execution of any system call by another user space thread at the syscall interface" 
Does that mean the each thread performs the system call individually?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, @user22215161, but of course each userspace thread performs its system calls independently of the others. And one of the features of an SMP (symmetric multi-processing) operating system, such as recent-ish Windows, MacOS, and typical builds of Linux, is that the kernel is multi-threaded, so it can *process* multiple system calls simultaneously.

Comment: It is the method comment for socket accept, 
    // Returns 1 on success, or IOStatus.UNAVAILABLE (if non-blocking and no
    connections are pending) or IOStatus.INTERRUPTED.
    
   I thought the comment was talking about a multi-threaded environment, and got confused..

Comment: @user22215161 "non-blocking" in that comment is about the configuration of the socket itself -- whether an attempt to accept a connection should wait, if necessary, until one is available.  That has nothing in particular to do with action by one thread interfering with action by another.

Comment: ah.. is that means when the current socket is in non-blocking mode?
I have a question related to this, then why does Tomcat only have one acceptor thread? Wouldn't it be better to create multi threads to handle accept?

Comment: We are now ranging rather far afield, @user22215161, but no, it generally does not make sense to have multiple acceptor threads.  Perhaps you are thinking of having additional threads *other than* the acceptor thread, to do work while the acceptor thread is waiting to accept a connection, and Tomcat *does* have that.  In an application designed around blocking accept calls, the acceptor thread generally will do nothing other than accept connections and assign servicing of those connections to other threads.